# Need to implement a web server to handle sql queries and html web pages

Tags: html, sql-server, webserver

For my databasing class, I need to create a working remote database. The database itself is not of issue, but I am quite ignorant on the specifics of a web server.

I need to:

-Have a web site where users can select SQL queries and/or construct their own 
-Have those queries sent to the database 
-print the results of the query on the web site (formatted for readability)

I have a strong understanding of java and SQL, what I don't know are the options for hosting the server, how clients will access it, and the html for displaying generated results (as opposed to static content)

I am aware of server implementations such as apache tomcat and java database stuff like JDBC, but I don't really know how they are used and where they fit in.

I apologize if this is too unfocused of a question but any help with understanding what I will need to learn specifically will be greatly appreciated

Comment: You need to implement a *web server* or just a *web application*? Big difference. I suspect/hope it is the latter.

Comment: sorry, a web application, though it does need to be hosted on our own server or the university account

Comment: np; just wanted to be clear on that part :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with some basic steps.

- Install Tomcat
- Install mysql
- Install an IDE like eclipse
- Create a sample web project and you can google for helloworld servlet
- convert that servlet to access the database and then you can implement the other functionality.

Here is some tuts

http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently working on a similar application that makes a request to a Java Servlet that then retrieves data from the database and sends it back. I'm not sure if this is what you are trying to do, but it's been working for me. I would create a java class that extends from a HttpServlet and have its `doGet(HttpServletRequest request HttpServletResponse response)` method deal with all of your database access. Once you have the information you need, you can either ship it back to the Javascript of you applicaiton as simple HTML, XML, or JSON. From there, it's just a matter of parsing what you send back and putting things in the proper place in the HTML with Javascript. I highly recommend looking into jQuery and AJAX for this sort of thing.